# entity framework oracle booleans migration

Tags: oracle, frameworks, boolean, migration, entity

I'm working on a project with visual studio 2010 using the entity framework. the whole project was running over SQLServer2008R2 and everything worked fine. Now, I need to migrate from SQLServer2008R2 to oracle 11.2. the fact is that I have many booleans on my code, but oracle don't support bool. I've been reading in lots of forums and everywhere the people said to put

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
  <settings>
    <add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />
  </settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

on the `App.config` and how it didn't worked, I've added the Oracle.DataAccess DLL to the project.

anyway Visual Studio is still with the same error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'short'
```

and the mapping is not done.

I just want to map the Int16 to Bool, because we have all the project working over SQLServer....

any idea?